# How to prevent git commit --no-verify command?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I would like to setup a pre-commit hook for all git repos to validate syntax errors using jshint and phplint. But the issue is that the git has a feature which can skip pre-commit hook from happening by using `--no-verify` flag. But i don't need to use that option. Can i prevent that `--no-verify` flag for git Please suggest a way.

Comment: I would recommend instead using CI Testing like [TravisCI](http://travis-ci.org/) to verify content rather than try to do partial testing as commit hooks. It cannot be circumvented, and it can do full tests rather than just syntax checks.

Comment: Pull requests, code review and continuous integration are the way to go. Having said that, the hook `prepare-commit-msg` may be useful. It's also invoked when committing but isn't bypassed by `--no-verify`. Note, however, that the documentation says "it should not be used as replacement for pre-commit hook." (I don't know why.)

Comment: There's no way to enforce a pre-commit hook (or any other client-side hook). Users can always decide to not use it.

Comment: I think it's bad practice to dictate in such detail what is supposed to happen on a developer machine when they decide to commit. The commonly used precommit hook "lint-staged" in the js/node world for example is still broken for partial commits - a legitimate feature of git. Controlling linting and tests at the moment when the code is about to be reviewed and merged into upstream is a way better approach as someone else here commented. Precommit hooks can be a source of frustration.

Answer (score 24):

First off: you can't definitively prevent someone from passing the `--no-verify` option.  That said, it's a good practice to use `pre-commit` hooks for linting, and it's a good practice to avoid passing the `--no-verify` option without reason.

If, however, you want to make it more cumbersome to pass the `--no-verify` option, you could:

1. generate a verification token and append it to the commit message in `pre-commit`;
2. exit `pre-receive` with a non-zero exitcode if this token is missing or invalid.  (Examples of things you can do in pre-receive hooks: https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/pre-receive-hooks)

Someone determined to avoid passing `--no-verify` could manually do step 1, which is why this isn't 100% effective.  I wouldn't recommend setting this up in a professional context, but I'm all for people using the tools at their disposal to instill good habits for themselves, while learning more about git hooks.

Comment: You could run the code that gets the verification token and use it on your own commits that didn't use the hook. It does not really prevent skipping the hook, also trying to prevent skipping the hooks is bad practice and bad organization culture. Don't babysit people with this controlling, condescending practice.

Comment: @timotgl well, sure; all you can do is make it arbitrarily annoying to avoid the hook.  It's a good point, though, and I've edited my answer to make this clearer.

FWIW, I agree that we shouldn't police developers but *strongly* disagree that linting should be left until merge / CI, especially when working in teams.  Code style guides enforced as close to code editing as possible - or, better yet, automated using tools like Prettier - are less time-consuming and more usable, and therefore more likely to be respected.

Comment: "You shouldn't be able to save your code unless you run my middleware" what a great idea

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a problem that should never be solved.

Answer (score 1):

git hooks are a client-side validation (think of it as a frontend), if you want to be sure validation is never skipped you need to do it on CI (backend).

---

Having said that here's my personal opinion about git hooks: it's a good practice to prevent devs to merge a PR in case linter, tests, etc don't pass.
But do it on CI, don't enforce it prematurely on the client side. It will unnecessarily slow down the development process. Allow devs to decide when they want to fix linter issues instead of saying "you can't commit until you make it perfect". That will allow them to focus on solving the problem they are working on instead of having to think in code style standards

Comment: While your opinion is valid, it may be easier to automatically format the code locally and force the few manual formats to be done before pushing. That ensures that the branch is always compliant. With the use of opinionated linters like prettier becoming more popular when using automated linting I think it makes sense to automate this chore as much as possible on the client. In my experience this leads to even less downtime since the code is always formatted even if they don't manually install the tools into their text editor.

Comment: @Buttars 100% agree, but you don't need hooks for that. Nowadays, all editors support format on save out of the box. Why penalize all engineers just because some don't have their editor configured correctly?

Comment: It's not about penalizing them. It's about giving each engineer an editor independent way of running the formatter automatically without needing them to install specific tools. For example at my company we have people who use vscode, intelij, web storm, and I personally use neovim. If I had to provide configurations for each of these it would quickly turn into an unmaintainable nightmare. I've never had an issue with a dev being upset about formatting because prettier does the majority of the heavy lifting. If it was frequently requiring manual input then I would reconsider.

Comment: It's not "specific tools", auto fix on save comes with any modern editor. If you don't use a modern editor is your choice, no need to force everyone else on the team to have an extra step on their flow.

Comment: And there's no need to provide configurations for each editor. Eg, if you use ESlint, only the .eslintrc file is needed

Comment: You're assuming that all engineers in the org/project will care enough or know to do that. That's not how standards work. My philosophy is that if it's not automated don't expect it to be done.

Comment: They will care if you block their PRs with a Github Action that runs the linter. That's how any modern setup works, I'm not inventing anything new

Answer (score 1):

If your IDE prevented you saving until the linting passed, would you consider that a positive?  Preventing users from commiting and pushing is equivalent to disallowing saving until an arbitrary set of conditions is met. If a developer has their hard drive suddenly fail, all in flight work is lost.

While this pre-commit pattern is popular, it's good to keep in mind the risks that are created for questionable gain.  It is an unnecessary and questionable game to be playing which can better be handled by CI scripts.

(And this isn't even mentioning how it slows down development by making the commit command take large amounts of time for those who commit often.)

Answer (score 0):

At the side of your VSCode, go to getLens for installed applications, then click on the settings icon. Then click on "Extension Settings". At the top, there is an input box for search, just enter "git". You will see "git (81)". Click on it and then check the box for "Allow No Verify Commit"