# How to prevent the skipping of Git Hooks

Tags: git, githooks

Is there some config you can set to make git strict where it is not possible to skip hooks. I've set up some hooks to lint and fix my teammates javascript code, but some of them keep skipping the hooks with `--no-verify` option because they think it's an error.

Is it possible to prevent the skipping of hooks?

Comment: why not block merges, PRs, or do it as a push hook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent git commit --no-verify command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519739/how-to-prevent-git-commit-no-verify-command)

Comment: If I run `git clone`, the repo I make is *my* repo. You cannot stop me from doing anything I want with it. I can skip hooks, I can copy your commits and claim the new ones are mine, and so on. You cannot control someone *else*'s repo, so put any controls you want to enforce in *your* repo, or one you control, not one they control. In particular, if you have control over a centralized repository to which others push or make pull requests, put the verification *there*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't provide a way to force the use of hooks. There are several cases in which the command accepts `--no-verify` to allow the overriding of these hooks on a case-by-case basis.

Git allows this because it can be useful to commit in-progress work without needing to run an expensive lint check and come back later to clean it up, or as an alternative to `git stash`. Experienced developers do this frequently.

Even if Git did provide this functionality, nothing would stop the developer from deleting the hook or removing the executable bit to prevent it from running, or commenting out the command to run. The user owning the clone is presumed (in the standard Unix fashion) to be competent and capable of making their own decisions about what hooks to run, and consequently hooks are not intended to be used in an adversarial context.

If you want to enforce a coding style and lint rules, you should do that with a CI job. You can configure your CI system to lint your code and check style rules, possibly on a per-commit basis, and disallow merging unless the checks pass. For checks which are more subjective, code review can be helpful (and is recommended regardless).

This isn't to say that hooks can't be useful in helping developers catch problems earlier, but they can't be forced on a user. Developers may be more open to using them if they know the CI system will fail their merge if the hooks don't pass. It's also possible that they may choose to disable potentially expensive hooks and let the more powerful CI system do the checks for them, and that's also a legitimate approach.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was thinking about using a CI job to do it.