# pre-receive hook to block no-verify

Tags: git, githooks

I am new to git concept.
I am trying to enforce users to use the provided client side hooks (a pre-commit hook that formats code before committing). But as we know, pre-commit hook check can be skipped with **--no-verify** option.
I am trying to create possibly a flag somewhere in git commit that can be checked in pre-receive hook, and if the flag is not there, the commit is going to be rejected.
I find the idea of adding a verification token in commit message itself from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639396/4381476
But this can be added manually as well!

My question would be, is there any way to add invisible flag to commit (rather than appending to commit message) which can be checked in pre-receive hook in the server side?

Due to severe lack of documentation on this, some pointers/ help would be great!

Comment: Everything can be emulated at the client side. The only solution is to repeat all checks at the server side and accept or reject commits based on results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this.  Whatever you do on the client side can be modified by the user and avoided with `--no-verify`, `git commit-tree`, or just tooling that uses libgit2 instead of Git.  Such tooling does exist and users may use it on their system as part of a development tool.

The proper place to do these checks is on the server, either in a `pre-receive` hook or in your CI system, coupled with code review.  You should have code review anyway (because it's good at catching bugs and security issues), but you also need it to make sure developers don't just remove or disable the linting code.

When you have effective controls like these, developers will be incentivized to ensure their code is formatted properly (or lints cleanly, as appropriate) because they won't want to have to fix it and push a fixed version of the code.

To quote from the [relevant portion of the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusehookstopreventusersfrommakingcertainchanges):

> It’s common to try to use `pre-commit` hooks (or, for commit messages, `commit-msg` hooks) to check these things, which is great if you’re working as a solo developer and want the tooling to help you. However, using hooks on a developer machine is not effective as a policy control because a user can bypass these hooks with `--no-verify` without being noticed (among various other ways). Git assumes that the user is in control of their local repositories and doesn’t try to prevent this or tattle on the user.
>
> In addition, some advanced users find `pre-commit` hooks to be an impediment to workflows that use temporary commits to stage work in progress or that create fixup commits, so it’s better to push these kinds of checks to the server anyway.

I use a workflow like the one mentioned in the last paragraph, and I find `pre-commit` hooks to be irksome for those reasons, so I strongly encourage you to push this to the server side as suggested.